# Convert image sequence to lossless movie

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, movie

I have a sequence of images in TIF format, and I would like to create a movie at a fixed FPS (say 10 images per second) and that is lossless. Is there an easy way to do that? I've been trying with `convert` from Imagemagick, and `ffmpeg`, but I just can't figure out what settings to use to avoid any compression.

Comment: If you have a Mac, you can use apple script and quicktime. Do you have access to a Mac?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/ffmpeg-create-video-from-images

Comment: `ffmpeg -r 15 -i img%04d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -b 800k -filter minterpolate='fps=120' out.mp4")` works quite well for me

Comment: Another hint: also check different `fps=` settings. Lower/higher fps may be better contingent on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try using a lossless codec, e.g. [HuffYUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffyuv) or [FFV1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFV1):

- `ffmpeg -i frame%04d.png -c:v huffyuv test.avi`
- `ffmpeg -i frame%04d.png -c:v ffv1 -qscale:v 0 test.avi`

Both codecs look portable.  HuffYUV appears to be the more popular, but for some reason, huffyuv encoding seems broken on my system, and I get weird colors and black horizontal banding.  It could have something to do with the input being RGB (from PNG) and not YUV (input from a raw YUV420 video file works OK).  So here are some alternatives (not completely lossless, but visually quite good):

- `ffmpeg -i frame%04d.png -qscale:v 0 test.avi`
- `ffmpeg -i frame%04d.png -c:v mjpeg -qscale:v 0 test.avi`

Comment: HuffYUV does have support for RGB, so I'm not sure it thats the issue.

Comment: I think almost by definition mjpeg will NOT be lossless. HuffYUV is, but it might introduce rounding errors due to color conversion. I cannot state anything about FFV1. However, I would like to draw attention to the lossless H264 option: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#LosslessH.264

Comment: How can I make each image to be exactly 1 frame and make the output file have FPS of 1 (Without replicating the images, just play slowly)? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi what I do is `ffmpeg -r <DESIRED_FPS> -f image2 -s <FRAME_WIDTH>x<FRAME_HEIGHT> -i ./frames/frame_%d.png -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p ./output.mp4`

The part you're interested in is the `-r <FPS>` flag.