# Creating a video from a single image for a specific duration in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How do I generate a movie using ffmpeg using a single image (image1.png) for a duration of 15 seconds with a specific resolution so when I play the video, the image will appear on screen for 15 seconds.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4
```

- The -t 15 makes it 15 seconds long.
- The -vf scale=320:240 sets the
  width/height.

Make sure to use the latest ffmpeg version e.g. http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=1280:1024'
scale=1280:1024: Invalid argument`
Any idea why?

Comment: @Equanox I've had the same issue, but it was caused by the "\" sign when copying and pasting. Removing it solves the issue.

Comment: When I try to run this, I get an error: Option loop not found - I'm using ffmpeg version 2.8.4 on windows

Comment: It works when I removed `-c:v libx264` -- it complains not finding the library.

Comment: while using jpeg image it takes a lot of time to execute in android. how can i solve this?

Comment: @YanKingYin the libx264 is a non GPL library, which might be missing. If you want to install it, you can do so (on mac using mac ports) by: 'port install ffmpeg +nonfree'

Comment: It answers the question, but I don't like the use of all those redundant additions in the command.

Comment: @joey Me neither, especially because OP did not ask for anything specific. You want to make a video from a single pic and don't care about any details at all? `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -t 5 out.mp4`

Comment: Perfect.  Worked

Comment: This is great, but...it takes forever and melts my CPU to generate a 40 minute video based on a single 720p PNG image. Is there a way to speed it up? Compression doesn't matter as long as it stays under a couple GB.

Comment: Note that if you need to specify the framerate (e.g. you want to concat this with existing video and need them to match) you can add e.g. `-r 30` before output to specify 30 FPS

Comment: @DoeJohnson YEAH, much simpler command. I think FFmpeg is smart enough to figure out the basics

Comment: `-loop 1` is necessary, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Be aware to blow your Video Size with just 1 single Image! look at my example below

Answer (score 18):

Found this to be faster:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/10 -i DJI_0024.JPG -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 out.mp4
```

-t 10 making the video 10 seconds long, and setting -framerate 1/10. Divisor of framerate should be same number as the argument to -t.
This made a jpeg with large resolution to be converted to a video in less then a second for me, while the other answer took about 40 sec.
Also resulting filesize became slightly smaller. from 3.38MB to 3.17MB

Answer (score 13):

For *high quality* and *encoding speed* (shown here with HEVC, select the codec and its codec specific settings for compatibility in your use case):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i input.jpg -t 15 \
    -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=3840:2160,loop=-1:1" \
    -movflags faststart \
    out.mp4
```

- `-framerate 30` rather than default 25 fps
- `-t 15` video duration 15 seconds
- `-c:v libx265` encode using h.265 (HEVC)
- `-x265-params lossless=1` lossless encoding, prevent artifacts for a still image. Unlike video, the image will be displayed for long enough to notice artifacts
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` set pixel format for compatibility since input is an image (JPEGs are often YUV444, which many decoders will not accept)
- `-vf "<options>"` sets video filter
- `scale=3840:2160` specifically scale to 3840x2160 (4K)

  - You will want to use `3840:-1` or `-1:2160` if your input is not **exactly** 16:9 (or whatever your target ratio is). This will prevent significant blurring due to an unintentional aspect ratio change. [Look into `pad` or `crop` instead](https://superuser.com/questions/547296/resizing-videos-with-ffmpeg-avconv-to-fit-into-static-sized-player/1136305#1136305), if you must have an exact resolution that does not match the ratio of the input.
- `loop=-1:1` infinitely loop (-1) for groups of 1 frame (1)
- `movflags faststart` will put metadata at front of file for faster playback in web browsers.

I am running this in a cloud/serverless environment, so minimizing runtime is key. I tried the low framerate approach, but it did not play in my target environment or locally on VLC.

The `-vf loop` option is what loops the one frame here. It keeps that frame in memory and is the **main reason** why this is faster than other answers, while being more compatible than a fractional framerate approach.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the options, saves a bunch of time trying to understand.

Comment: What if I have 10 images I want displayed each a half second, for a 5 second video ?

Comment: If you haven't already searched: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

**Be aware to blow your Video Size with just 1 single Image!**
Do this:
use ffmpeg  with the Parameter `-r 0.01` for almost no frame rate. This makes the file about 65% smaller
But you maybe also need to cut the length with  this Paramter `-ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:27`

heres my code:

```
ffmpeg -r 0.01 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -preset  ultrafast -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:27   -c:a aac  -b:a 96k -pix_fmt yuv420p  -shortest out.mp4 -y
```