# add multiple images to a video using aws mediaconvert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-media-convert, aws-elemental

I'm trying to add images to a video using mediaconvert. I used mediaconvert graphic overlay/ image inserter to perform this task. However, the image is overriding the given video in the output for the given duration. I want the image to be still at first and then start the video from the beginning if I add an image and similarly for the rest of the images. Can this be done by using aws-mediaconvert?

Answer (score 0):

Overlays are normally used for things like watermarks and logos or simple sports scores/news tickers etc. Images you want to appear over the top of the video.

You could create a clip of blank video to insert into your output, then apply the overlay to just that?

Another option is to [convert the image to a video yourself with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891342/creating-a-video-from-a-single-image-for-a-specific-duration-in-ffmpeg) and insert that into your output?