# Not able to generate a video from image URLS

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using image urls to generate video using ffmpeg but a blank video is generated:
PFB my command:

***ffmpeg -framerate 1  -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i https://tstatic//file.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 output.mp4***

Here https://tstatic//file.jpg will be replaced by actual URL

I ran the above command

Comment: To create a video from an image, you have to use the loop option : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891342/creating-a-video-from-a-single-image-for-a-specific-duration-in-ffmpeg

Comment: i dont want to use loop.i want to create video from image urls.

Comment: I have some URLs  which points to images. IN ffmpeg , instaed of using image files i want to use these urls to generate a video.