# Script to make movie from images

Tags: ffmpeg, photos, movies

Hello I want a script or a way to make a video from images. I have a folder with a lot of pictures named randomly like "flowers.jpg", "tree.jpg", etc.

I also have an "intro.jpg" photo which I want to add at the start of every video.

What I want exactly is to create a video (any format, .avi etc) for a custom duration with only two photos like this:
intro.jpg (10-20 seconds or how much i want) + tree.jpg (1 hour or how much i want)
intro.jpg + flowers.jpg
...
and so on.

Sorry for being a newbie, but I have no clue how to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you asking for a tool suggestion or guidance as to how to go about writing for a program that does this? You should probably clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to use a free online creation tool. You can just upload you photos and specify the duration. You can also add audio and transitions.

My daughter uses Animoto
https://animoto.com/

or you could try this.

https://www.wevideo.com/

If you just want to make the video locally it is easy in Adobe Premiere, iMovie, Sony Vegas or any number of easy to use programs with free version or free trials.

By script do you mean code and if so under what environment? You can use FFMpeg which is open source and command line and execute from code.

[FFmpeg create video from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/ffmpeg-create-video-from-images)

If you want guidance in building the FFMpeg script or just want to use ffmpeg locally try a GUI for ffmpeg such as

http://www.free-codecs.com/download/ffmpegGUI.htm