# ffmpeg not creating video from images

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I have read this [Create Video using ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

[Stack Question for the Same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/ffmpeg-create-video-from-images)

[Wiki Page for the same](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence)

Still I am not able to get it.
I have written this shell command in PHP

```
echo $make_movie = "$ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i $folder_name/img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p $folder_name/output.mp4";
```

This gives output

```
ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -framerate 1/5 -i ankit/img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p ankit/output.mp4

if(shell_exec($make_movie)){
    echo "<br />Movie Created..<br />";
}
else{
    echo "<br />Movie Creation Error..<br />";
}
```

The Output is Movie Creation Error that means the Shell Command is not executing?

Questions:

1. What is wrong?
2. For future use, any debugging methods for this?

I ran the same command on cmd and it made the video..!!!

Comment: Remove the echo statement from variable assignment. I.e Change `echo $make_move=` to  `$make_movie=` and then run `exec($make_movie)`

Comment: that is just to check the output of the query generated..

Comment: it means that shell_exec return a NULL or empty string, signifying no output or error. DOn't use shell_exec. use `exec()` instead, which can capture all of the output, and give you an exit code as well.

Comment: @MarcB, I increased the maximum execution time and restarted apache, it worked! My code was working already...

Comment: Humble request to know why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec is pretty useless when it comes to figuring out why your command failed. use exec() instead:

```
$last_line = exec($make_movie, $all_output, $exit_code);
var_dump($exit_code);
```

You'll have to look at ffmpeg's docs to determine what the exit code means