# What is the file format for MP4 files

Tags: mp4

I would like to create a MP4 file from images.

Where could I find the documentation on MP4 binary file format.

similar to this: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

but for .MP4 files.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, especially a wheel as intricate as that. Use a third-party library or offload the work to some other process where all that hard work has already been done (e.g. ffmpeg).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FFmpeg create video from images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/ffmpeg-create-video-from-images)

Comment: This is for my own curiosity. And I don't mind reinventing the wheel. I find it fun!