# Exporting pyqtgraph to video

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I want to export a pyqtgraph to a video. Is there any easy way to do this? The plot is not much different from this example except it contains about 10000 frames:

```py
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
win.resize(1000,600)
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
p6 = win.addPlot(title="0")
curve = p6.plot(pen='y')
data = np.random.normal(size=(10,1000))
ptr = 0
def update():
    global curve, data, ptr, p6
    data_ptr = ptr%10
    p6.setTitle("%d" % data_ptr)
    curve.setData(data[data_ptr])
    if ptr == 0:
        p6.enableAutoRange('xy', False)
    ptr += 1
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every frame is simply a single image. So you could use the [imageexporter](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/pyqtgraph/exporters/ImageExporter.py) to generate an image for each of the frames. The `toBytes` argument of the export function will return the `*.png` file in memory, though you could also number them and save them in a temporary directory.
An example of exporting the graph to a file is given in the pyqtgraph [userguide](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/exporting.html#exporting-from-the-api).

You could then use ffmpeg to sequence them together.

If you went with the export to separate files option, you could use the ffmpeg command line as shown in:
[How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

However, if you stored all frames in memory, the ffmpeg python bindings could be used for that, though I have no example for that.

Comment: Looks like your ImageExporter link is out of date: https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/exporting.html

Comment: @headdab thanks, but it doesn't seem like a direct replacement. I can't seem to find proper documentation for the ImageExporter other than the source code. I'll update the answer with both a link to the new guide as well as to the source file.