# How to create a video from images on a .tif format with FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, format

I just discovered `FFmpeg`: awesome software. After reading this [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg) I could efficiently create a movie with pictures in a `.png` format with the following line:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

In an experiment, however, I took high quality pictures on a `.tif` format and would like to create a movie out of them. I just copied the line above and replaced the name of the files as well as the format `.png` by `.tif` but I got a message error saying "`This format is not supported`". Here is the report:

```
[tiff @ 0x7fce5c02a600] This format is not supported (bpp=12, bppcount=1)
Last message repeated 1 times
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[tiff @ 0x7fce5c01bc00] This format is not supported (bpp=12, bppcount=1)
Last message repeated 7 times
Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
Error marking filters as finished
Conversion failed!
```

Should I just forget it or is there a workaround with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Add -report to the cmd and share the report.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan for the answer. I copied the report

Comment: Yes, not supported. FFmpeg does support upto 16 bpc RGB TIFFs or 8 bit YUV TIFFs or 16 bit grayscale ones..

Comment: thanks for the comment @Gyan. Do you know another software that could do the job?

Comment: Try imagemagick