# Creating RTSP/RTMP h264 encoding stream from bitmaps

Tags: c#, video, encoding, bitmap, h.264

I have some rtsp stream which I combine into bitmaps. Now  I need to encode these with h.264 and send using rtsp or rtmp stream.

I got some advice to use ffmpeg, but I have no clue how to supply byte array (or Bitmap) to it. And also can`t find a way to create that kind of stream.

Sending decoded bitmap is really bandwidth heavy, I expect to compress it by encoding to h264

Comment: I don't think you want to do this in software.  Real-time conversion in software is probably not doable.  I think you need a CODEC.  See following : https://www.vcodex.com/an-overview-of-h264-advanced-video-coding/

Comment: If you just want to understand how to use ffmpeg to convert images to video, with whatever encoding you want, then answers like this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966617/334402