# ffmpeg video length is 0 when concatenating pictures

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, concatenation, frames

I'm trying to concatenate individual frames, but the video length is 0 and all frames seemingly play at once. Iv'e tried increasing the video length in ffmpeg and changing the frame rate.

```
os.system('ffmpeg -f concat -i List_tb.txt -c copy output.mp4')
os.system("ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -filter:v fps=fps=120 output_temp.mp4")
os.system("ffmpeg -i output_temp.mp4 -filter:v setpts=8.0*PTS final.mp4")
```

also the frame rate is the amount of frames

Comment: Print List_tb.txt and share log of first command

Comment: where can i find the log?

Comment: Rerun the command with -report added and look in the working directory.

Comment: ffmpeg started on 2019-11-09 at 19:16:57
Report written to "ffmpeg-20191109-191657.log"
Command line:
"C:\\FFmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -f concat -safe 0 -i List_tb.txt -c copy output.mp4 -report
ffmpeg version N-94335-g9869e21776 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190716

Comment: That's the start. Add the whole log.

Comment: its too long. Do you want the whole thing?

Comment: Upload the whole thing to pastebin

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PQmbUfj8

Comment: You don't **concat** (stitch) PNG bytes together and call it an MP4 file. I don't know how that even worked with `-codec copy`.

Comment: PS try: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i List_tb.txt -t 5 -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`. Alternatively try [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24966617/2057709).

Comment: PNG is an acceptable codec inside MP4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since images don't have inherent timestamps, the concat demuxer is failing to generate a smooth monotonic sequence of timestamps for the packets it generates. You can work around this by specifying a duration directive for each file, within the list i.e.

```
file '-1.1257558476894771_10_1_0j.png'
duration 0.04
file '-0.8103308013367797_10_1_0j.png'
duration 0.04
file '1.0805993584315776_10_1_0j.png'
duration 0.04
...
```

where `0.04` is the duration in seconds for one frame at 25 fps.