# Azure Kinect: How to get a depth video recording in color?

Tags: azure, kinect, depth, recording

I am trying to extract the depth video from a recording (mkv), but the problem is that its extracted in grayscale b16g format. Is it possible to extract or obtain the depth video with color as viewed in the Azure Kinect Viewer? Camera used is Azure Kinect DK. 
Thanks, any feedback is appreciated.

This is the steps I used:

> ffmpeg -i output.mkv -map 0:1 -vsync 0 depth%03d.png

this extracts the depth track as a sequence of 16-bit PNGs. 
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kinect-dk/record-file-format

then

> ffmpeg -r 30 -i depth%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf “fps=30,format=yuv420p” depth.mp4

recreates the depth video from the png images. but the output video is in grayscale.
Source: [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

The viewer normalizes the depth based on depth modes min and max depth so that the entire 16bit depth range is used. Then it uses the following code to colorize.

```
    static inline BgraPixel ColorizeBlueToRed(const DepthPixel &depthPixel,
                                              const DepthPixel &min,
                                              const DepthPixel &max)
    {
        constexpr uint8_t PixelMax = std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max();

        // Default to opaque black.
        //
        BgraPixel result = { 0, 0, 0, PixelMax };

        // If the pixel is actual zero and not just below the min value, make it black
        //
        if (depthPixel == 0)
        {
            return result;
        }

        uint16_t clampedValue = depthPixel;
        clampedValue = std::min(clampedValue, max);
        clampedValue = std::max(clampedValue, min);

        // Normalize to [0, 1]
        //
        float hue = (clampedValue - min) / static_cast<float>(max - min);

        // The 'hue' coordinate in HSV is a polar coordinate, so it 'wraps'.
        // Purple starts after blue and is close enough to red to be a bit unclear,
        // so we want to go from blue to red.  Purple starts around .6666667,
        // so we want to normalize to [0, .6666667].
        //
        constexpr float range = 2.f / 3.f;
        hue *= range;

        // We want blue to be close and red to be far, so we need to reflect the
        // hue across the middle of the range.
        //
        hue = range - hue;

        float fRed = 0.f;
        float fGreen = 0.f;
        float fBlue = 0.f;
        ImGui::ColorConvertHSVtoRGB(hue, 1.f, 1.f, fRed, fGreen, fBlue);

        result.Red = static_cast<uint8_t>(fRed * PixelMax);
        result.Green = static_cast<uint8_t>(fGreen * PixelMax);
        result.Blue = static_cast<uint8_t>(fBlue * PixelMax);

        return result;
    }
```

https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/95f1d95f1f335b57a350a80a3a62e98e1ee4258d/tools/k4aviewer/k4adepthpixelcolorizer.h#L35