# Fastest way to create a video from image array

Tags: javascript

What is the fastest way to create 1 second video from image array:

```
        var frames = []

        function capture(time) {
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(player, 0, 0, 640, 480);
            preview.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 640, 480);
            var imgString = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp', 1);
            frames.push(imgString);
            requestAnimationFrame(capture)
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(capture)
```

Code above continuously "captures" an image from a live stream `player`. 
What would be the fastest way continuously create video chunks for this continuous image capture?

Comment: Fastest in what sense? Code simplicity? Performance?

Comment: The fastest is probably to decapitate the lossless images you get (i.e. extract the pure VP8L chunk), then manually stuff WebP image data into ANMF frames, following the description of [WebP format spec](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container). However, you'll end up with a huge file if you don't diff the frames to find the bounding box of the changes between frames, and crop the frames accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to make the video, rather than specifically doing this in javascript code, would be to use ffmpeg.

See: [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Mind you, on closer reading, this likely won't work for continuous output, which I think you indicate wanting.