# Javascript creating a video with a picture and a song

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, node-modules, editing

I want to know if a method or a library exist for making a mp4 file from a mp3 file and a jpeg file
(.mp3 + .jpeg = .mp4)

thanks for everybody who will help me

Answer (score 1):

You should look into ffmpeg, it is a collection of very useful tools to manipulate audio and video. There is an NPM package for it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

This is a guide on how to make a video from image(s) with ffmpeg.

[How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: i found this `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i inputimage.jpg -i inputaudio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest outputfile.mp4` but when i start the file i got an error could you help me ?

Comment: @Nenatik no one can help you fix an invisible error. Use [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63403591/edit) to update your question with all relevant **information** about what you've tried (code) and what error you got (text).