# How to replace the video track in a video file with a still image?

Tags: image, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to replace the video track in a video file with a still image. I tried some commands I got from other questions such as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

`ffmpeg -i x.png -i orig.mp4 final.mp4`

`ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i x.png -r 30 -i orig.mp4 final.mp4`

But these didn't work. I'm not sure which of these arguments are required or not. The output should be accepted by YouTube as a valid video - I was able to simply remove the video track, but apparently they don't let you upload a video without a video track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try looping the still image like this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i x.png -i orig.mp4 final.mp4
```

Then you can tweak the encoding process by introducing the following quality parameters:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i x.png -i orig.mp4 -crf 22 -preset slow final.mp4
```

they are described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

If your colorspace gets rejected by YouTube you can try adding: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

**Solution:** A final solution is something like this:

- *Where `-t 30` is an example duration of 30 seconds.*
- *Using `-c:a copy` will directly copy the original audio without a new re-encoding (is faster).*

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i x.png -i orig.mp4 -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 22 -preset slow -c:a copy -shortest final.mp4
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `-shortest` output option or else it will loop forever. YouTube will accept just about any colorspace/chroma subsampling, so no need to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` for YouTube. Recommend adding the [`-map`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) output option so the default behavior doesn't choose the wrong streams: `-map 0 -map 1:a`.

Comment: Yeah, it was definitely looping forever. Note that you have to put `-shortest` before the output path. Thanks @pszemus and @llogan.

Comment: @cornerstore can you mark it as an accepted answer then?