# Combine images into video (with audio in background) in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, merge, combine

I have a folder with 15 images and 1 audio file:

image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg ..... and music.webm

(Also resolution of images is 1440x720)

I want to combine these images into a video with audio in background.And framerate I require is 0.2 (5 second for each frame).I gave a search on Stackoverflow and I found the nearest example and tried.But it failed.

`ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%03d.jpg -i music.webm output.mp4`

(Actually I have very little knowledge of ffmpeg so please excuse my foolishness)

Please help me with my issue.(Also I didn't understood where in the code I have to enter framerate)

Edit:-If needed I can easily tweak with filename of images.Be free to tell me that too

Answer (score 1):

How your command failed? please paste the text.

According to your image file format, the pattern should be:  `%3d`, but not `%03d`

e.g.

- `image_%d.jpg` apply to:  image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg
- `image_%04d.jpg` apply to: image_0001.jpg, image_0002.jpg ... image9999.jpg

and also , when using this "pattern sequence", MAKE SURE:

1. the sequence should start from xxx001.jpg, otherwise you should specify a parameter `-start_index` or something.
2. the sequence must not broken. e.g. `image5.jpg`, `image6.jpg`, (missing 7 ) `image8.jpg`

refer:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -r 0.2 -i image_%02d.jpg -i music.webm -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -preset veryslow -acodec copy video.mkv
```

So -r specifies fps (I actually didn't try using a float value there, but try it)

-vcodec specifies video codec, -crf quality, preset the encoding speed (slower is more efficient), -acodec copy says audio should be copied.

I think that should work, give it a try. You will need to rename the images to image_01.jpg image_02...

Also have a look here: [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: [Image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) option is `-framerate`.

Comment: @llogan I tried it some time ago too, -r for specifying framerate also works as it should (I also would have seen no reason for it not to work). However I didn't try it with float numbers.