# Bash command to join a sequence of images into a video

Tags: image, image-processing, ffmpeg, sequence

Is there a command for ffmpeg that can convert images to a video? Specifying framerate would be useful as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: This seems to be answer. Thank you guys.