# Colors not accurate in ffmpeg video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am creating a video with ffmpeg by stringing together a bunch of PNG files. The resulting video has horizontal lines running across it and the colors are not accurate. Here's the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i img%04d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p timer.mp4
```

I am attaching an example of one of the input PNG files and a frame from the video. Can anyone tell what's wrong?

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQNzp.png)
[video frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfYWr.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to So, is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg) your answer?