# Create a video from sequence of images on HTML

Tags: javascript, opencv, ffmpeg, webassembly

I want to create a video from sequence of images displayed on HTML.

ffmpeg may be possible but need `SharedArrayBuffer`  support, is it possible by using OpenCV.js?

Answer (score 0):

Xring that sounds like a lot of work just to get what is technically a Gif on screen. OpenCV is meant for AI styled work it's a bit overkill for this purpose.

How about [Creating videos from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg?rq=1) on the backend of your app and hosting that on your page. There are also a few examples of how you could do this to make gifs.

On Linux I'd cat all the images in a folder to ffmpeg like this

```
cat *.png | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -i - output.mp4
```

Comment: this will work, but my scenario is pure frontend like `https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/examples/browser/image2video.html` does.

as the question described, ffmpeg + wasm need `SharedArrayBuffer` support as per `https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm#installation`