# Using NodeJS to combine a png and mp3 to make a mp4

Tags: node.js, mp4

So I am trying to combine a mp3 file and png with nodejs to make a mp4 file. I tried searching for modules and such, but cannot find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fluent-ffmpeg` package:

For example of how ot work, here is an example of resizing a mp4:

```
var ffmpeg  = require( 'fluent-ffmpeg' );
ffmpeg( path.join( toDirectory, newVideo._id + '.orig.mp4' ) )
      .size( '1024x576' )
      .fps( 25 )
      .videoCodec( 'libx264' )
      .videoBitrate( '1024k' )
      .output( path.join( toDirectory, newVideo._id + '.mp4' ) )
      .audioBitrate( '92k' )
      .audioFrequency( 48000 )
      .audioChannels( 2 )
      .run();
```

For creating a mp4 from image with sound (Not tested):

```
var ffmpeg  = require( 'fluent-ffmpeg' );

let newMp4 = ffmpeg();
newMp4
    .input("./test.png")
    .input("./another.png")
    .addInput('/path/to/audio.file')
    .save("./test.mp4")
    .outputFPS(1) // Control FPS
    .frames(2) // Control frame number
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend using *ffmpeg*, by using this npm package *https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg*.

I think this answer would help you creating mp4 from png images and audio [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: how would i do it in nodejs? the answer is using the command line..

Comment: using npm package, you could pass ffmpeg commands in node js